# PL/SQL Oracle - Insert ID from Table 2 in Table 1 based on Name as key, which may be duplicate and update Table 2 if Name not found

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

PL/SQL - Insert ID from Table 2 in Table 1 based on Name as key, which may be duplicate and update Table 2 if Name not found in Oracle.

I have to create a stored Procedure which performs the above task

Given Table 1: TEST1

```
Name |  Data  | ID |
Tim  |  Test1 |    |
Jim  |  Test2 |    |
Jim  |  Test3 |    |
Roy  |  Test4 |    |
Matt |  Test5 |    |
```

Given Table 2: TEST2 (ID is generated automatically)

```
ID   |  Name  |
23   |  Tim   | 
24   |  Jim   | 
20   |  Matt  |
```

Need Resultant Table as:

```
Name |  Data  | ID |
Tim  |  Test1 | 23 |
Jim  |  Test2 | 24 |
Jim  |  Test3 | 24 |
Roy  |  Test4 | x  |
Matt |  Test5 | y  |
```

where x, y are newly generated ID for Roy and Matt if the Name is not found in TEST2

I have written below code:

```
MERGE INTO TEST1 b
USING (
  SELECT ID, NAME FROM TEST2) e
ON (b.NAME = e.NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.CODE = E.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (b.CODE)
  VALUES ('NONE');
```

which produces

```
Name |  Data  | ID |
Tim  |  Test1 | 23 |
Jim  |  Test2 | 24 |
Jim  |  Test3 | 24 |
Roy  |  Test4 | -  |
Matt |  Test5 | -  |
```

I am not getting the logic to simultaneously insert new row in TEST2 and fetch the data.

Please help!!

Comment: How  new ID values for table TEST2 are generated ?

Comment: This seems like a flawed process. You probably want to make the ID column in the second table the primary key, and use that in the first table. In that case you shouldn't also store the name in the first table. For now (assuming you are in the process of fixing that problem): What if the same name appears more than once in the second table? Then: first you should update the second table with the missing names, and then update the first table with the ID's. "Simultaneous" is the wrong idea; you must do it in two steps. You will need to lock the two tables for the duration.

Comment: @krokodilko ID IS generated through auto_increment in the TEST2 table

Comment: @mathguy yes I guess you are right...I need to have another SQL to handle the case of not matching...will keep digging.

Comment: @NishantPatel Do you want to implement it as trigger or as PL/SQL program? (I mean is it one time task or you want to achieve this on the fly on each insert). How do you want to generate IDs for rows not found in TEST2 table?

Comment: @fg78nc The ID is auto_increment, so triggers will also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try (ad-hoc PL/SQL, but you can change to procedure after testing)

```
DECLARE
  TYPE test_cur_type IS REF CURSOR RETURN test1%ROWTYPE;
  test_cur test_cur_type;
  test_row test1%rowtype;
BEGIN
  OPEN test_cur FOR SELECT name, data, id FROM test1;
  LOOP
    FETCH test_cur INTO test_row;
    EXIT WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND;
    INSERT INTO test3 (name, data, id)
    VALUES (test_row.name, test_row.data,
      NVL(SELECT id FROM test2 
           WHERE name=test_row.name AND ROWNUM <= 1, test_sequence.nextval));
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE test_cur;
END;
```

where test_sequence is

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    MAXVALUE 5000
    CACHE 20;
```

and both tables test2 and test3 have the following definitions for `id` column

```
id number default test_sequence.nextval
```

This script allows you to implement any complex logic on each row level and can be further optimized (if required (avoid pre-mature optimization) with bulk updates (avoid pl/sql - sql context switching overheads)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a soution, might be pretty naive, but for now has done my task. Below is the Code

```
create or replace procedure TestProc as
begin
MERGE INTO TEST2 T2
   USING (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM TEST1) T1
         ON (T1.NAME = T2.NAME)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (T2.NAME) VALUES (T1.NAME);
MERGE INTO TEST1 b
USING (
  SELECT ID, NAME
  FROM TEST2) e
ON (b.NAME = e.NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.CODE = E.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (b.CODE)
  VALUES ('NONE');
 end;
```

Further optimization and ideas are welcome. Thanks!!